# Turning autocrlf off using git --config

Tags: git, intellij-idea

As soon as I checkout code from GIT all my file ending change from LF to CRLF. I am using idea-intelliJ where I have set my file endings to be `UNIX and OS/X (\n)` that is LF but it always changes to CRLF. I notcied `git --config --list` has `core.autcrlf=true`. I tried the following things to change this to false but I am unable to do so.

`git config --global --replace-all core.autocrlf false`

`git config --replace-all core.autocrlf false`

`git config --global edit core.autocrlf false`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit config settings by directly editing the file. In this case you can change the config by going to `/path/to/your/project/.git`. The folder contains a config file that contains all the git settings for that project.

Comment: There are 2 core.autocrlf settings. One is true and one is false. In the .git folder there is only 1 setting (false). Not sure where the other one is coming from and it is set to true.